# Raspberry pi 2 shuts down when TV does

Tags: power

I had a rPi Model B for a long time... and now I got an rPi2 but I am having a small problem with it. I had the same problem with the 1st pi but I dont remember what I did to fix it.
Sometimes it goes offline from the local network. This happens 99.9% when the TV closes. I am pretty sure that's what's causing it.
I remember there was a checkbox i unticked to fix this on the pi 1 but I cant remember what exactly.

How can I have it always on?

I am using OSMC now on the pi2...and pi1 was running Raspbmc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it locks up each time you turn off the 'HDMI display', then the issue is related to the CEC features. That's how HDMI TV sets use HDCP protocol to interact with HDMI signal sources in various ways, including shutdown.

Since the RPi does not have any method to be awakened from shutdown, CEC shutdown features had best be disabled.

You should Google how to turn these off with OSMC.